# Noncompact and compact partial Cauchy surface

Tags: general-relativity, mathematical-physics, mathematics, topology

What is a lay terms explanation for the meaning of compactness and noncompactness of a surface, S or of an horizon?
In particular, I don't understand what a noncompact partial Cauchy surface is and what distinguishes it from a compact one.

Comment: This might be suited better for math.SE

Answer (score 1):

This is just the basic notion of compactness. In layman's terms, it refers to the finiteness of the hypersurface, it has a finite volume. The classical example of a compact partial Cauchy surface is Misner space, where every surface of constant $t < 0$ is a compact partial Cauchy surface, since their volume will just be the circumference of the manifold.

Comment: So a compact partal Cauchy surface has a finite volume, but what about the meaning of S being compact or not?

Comment: The meaning depends on the context. I assume you read about compact Cauchy horizons in Hawking's 92 papers judging by your other posts, which states that a Cauchy horizon can be compactly generated without breaking the weak energy condition only if it is compact. Or the fact that a compact Cauchy horizon will always be compactly generated if the horizon itself is compact. It doesn't mean anything by itself outside of the context of what you're trying to prove.

Comment: http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~bwrobert/research/RobertsB_CTCreview.pdf   In the link provided above, in page 8, it is claimed that S needs to be non-compact because a time machine would only enable us to go back to a finite part of history. But wouldn't then S be compact? Isn't compactness the property related to finiteness ? I am mixing now the concepts of compactly generated and compactness, too.

Answer (score 1):

Compactness is a mathematical notion. In finite dimension, being compact is equivalent to being bounded and closed (being closed for a set C means that for every sequence of points belonging to C and converging to some limit point $l$ in the whole space, that point $l$ belongs to C too).

A region may be "finite" (i.e. bounded) although not compact, as for example if a part of its boundary is a lightlike curve not belonging to this region.

Comment: But in the so-called Hawking's paper why does S being non-compact mean that the time machine is built in a finite region of time ?

Comment: Isn't it a consequence of S being either unbounded or not closed?

Comment: But if it were compact, the time machine would be located in a finite region of time as I understand it and not the other way round.

Comment: @Time traveler A region may be finite (i.e. bounded) although not compact, as for example if a part of its boundary is a lightlike curve not belonging to this region. See other examples in figure 1 of [this paper](http://www.ccom.ucsd.edu/~lindblom/Publications/10_CommMathPhys.61.87.pdf). The non-compactness comes here from being not closed.

Comment: @Time traveler I would be interested to know if that has answered your question.